# Wordpress - How to add active class to current menu item on only one specific menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, conditional-statements

So the following code works to get the current parent menu item active (highlighted with a different color background):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
  if (in_array('current-menu-parent', $classes) || in_array('current- 
  menu-item', $classes)){
    $classes[] = 'active';
  }
     return $classes;
}
```

My only problem is that it also highlights the footer menu items. I want it to only affect the primary menu. I've made the following attempts to try to get it to work (in addition to some variations):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 3);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item, $args) {
  if ($args->theme_location == 'primary' && in_array('current-menu- 
  parent', $classes) || in_array('current-menu- 
  item', $classes)){
    $classes[] = 'active';
  }
     return $classes;
}
```

and

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 3);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item, $args) {
  if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    if (in_array('current-menu-parent', $classes) || in_array('current- 
    menu-item', $classes)){
    $classes[] = 'active';
    }
  }
     return $classes;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The footer items are still affected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the outer, enclosing CSS selector in the footer, i.e. #footer, to target the menu and menu items.

```
#footer #menu .current-menu-parent {background-color:#000 !important;}
```

Use dev tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the exact selector.

Comment: I added the #main-menu selector (i.e. #main-menu .current-menu-parent) to the function with 2 parameters (the 1st one up top) and it didn't work. Sorry if I'm doing it wrong, still a beginner at PHP/JS.

Comment: What I meant is that you don't need the extra function. Use the one top function and then target the footer menu with specific CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Weird.. 3rd example is working for me.
Check wp_nav_menu() function calls, and menu areas in WP admin

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary'));//header
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondary'));//footer
```

And check WP version. You need 3.1+